# How to create a maths quiz using Python

Tags: python

I want to create a math game which asks about 5 questions of addition and that it will print the total score at the end and it will also tell which Ans is correct and which is wrong. I tried the following program but I'm not getting the correct result.Plz help me out.

```
import random()
def askquestion():
    
    score=0
    num1=random.randint(1,20)
    num2=random.randint(1,20)
    correctanswer=num1+num2
    answer=input(str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+"=")
    if answer==correctanswer:
        print("great work!!")
        score=score+10
    else:
        print("Uh-ohh! Let's try another one!")

askquestion()
askquestion()
askquestion()
askquestion()
```

Comment: `if answer=correctanswer:` is not even syntactically correct, aren't you getting an error on that line?

Comment: Try this: `if int(answer) == correctanswer:`.

Comment: You defined score in the mid of the function, it will "reset" every time you call function. Define it before function.

Comment: Same goes for `import random()`... Also, *I'm not getting the correct result* is not a clear problem statement. If you're getting errors - post them. If you get wrong output - post example inputs and what your expected output is

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm not getting errors the output is only showing that the answer is wrong and it is also not printing the final score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few adjustments and persisting the total score, a possible answer is:

```
import random
global_score = 0
def askquestion():
    score = 0
    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    num2 = random.randint(1,20)
    correctanswer = num1+num2
    answer = input(str(num1)+"+"+str(num2)+"=")
    if int(answer) == correctanswer:
        print("great work!!")
        score = score + 10
    else:
        print("Uh-ohh! Let's try another one!")
    return (score)
        
global_score = global_score + askquestion()
global_score = global_score + askquestion()
global_score = global_score + askquestion()
global_score = global_score + askquestion()

print ('Final Score: ', global_score)
```

**Adjustments:**

1. Correct the import random without ()
2. Correct the comparison in the if statement, == instead of =
3. Converted the answer to integer
4. Return the score of the question
5. Declared a global score and used to get the return of the function

Comment: return score would be enough, although return (score) will be evaluated to be an int too.

Comment: To make it a little more foolproof, you could use `if answer == str(correctanswer):`. So, it would not crash if something different than a number is entered. It would just count it as wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in the if statement, you must check with == not with = .
I hope this helped. :)

Comment: I did that but didn't worked

Comment: So you should cast the input to int before comparing. (with using ==)